# Get Microsoft teams public channel message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to get messages from teams public channel. I can get messages from the one which I am part of, but i want to retrieve messages from public channel which i am not part of.

There are few apis available on microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I created a app with all the appropriate application permissions.
I also requested for protected apis request from microsoft(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis).

But i still cannot get all the public channel messages and keep getting below error:

```
"response": {
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "UnknownError",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-06-30T00:48:11",
            "request-id": "25360f0f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-78fa36f30f1c",
            "client-request-id": "25360f0f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-78fa36f30f1c"
        }
    }
}
```

any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to decode the access token in jwt.io and make sure you have at least ChannelMessage.Read.All [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to read the message  , if the you don't have the required permission , please add it again and try to check in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) first, if its working fine .

Thanks

Comment: i can see that permission. The thing is i can get messages from channel which i am part of but i want to retrieve messages from channel(public) which i am not part of.

Comment: Oh , thanks for the update , in that case you should ask someone to add you in that channel , POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/ece6f0a1-7ca4-498b-be79-edf6c8fc4d82/channels/19%3A56eb04e133944cf69e603c5dac2d292e%40thread.skype/members
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
    "roles": [" "],
    "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('8b081ef6-4792-4def-b2c9-c363a1bf41d5')"
}  , ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request

Comment: is there any way I can get messages without getting added to that team/channel? Using an app or any other way that Microsoft allow.

Answer (score 0):

GET /teams/team-id/ is accessible only to team members or owner or admin. Only a person who is part of the team's roster or is an Admin (Global Admin or Teams Service Admin or AU Admin) can see anything under GET /teams/team-id/.

Even Admins cannot pull messages from channels they are not part of. That is by design.

Comment: i am global admin and i can get teams details irrespective being part in that team. What i want is to messages.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your request for protected APIs is approved?

Comment: I filled up the form for protected APIs approval but i didn't heard anything from Microsoft but the APIs started working for channel which I am part of. So i believe it has been approved.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, we will check and get back to you.

Comment: @AshishMittal - We got the following update from the engineering team - Admins cannot pull messages from channels they are not part of. That is by design.

Comment: So i cannot pull messages from channels which i am not part of whatsoever. Or their is any way?

Comment: Currently it is not possible.